# Google Firebase with multiple users

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

For making an app in Swift and storing data using Google Firebase, does each user have their own database? I have an app in which people can add meals to a meal plan and generate a random meal plan. Even if they close the app and reopen it, they should be able to generate a meal plan with the meals they previously added. This functionality works for the app. However, I am not sure if other users of the app will be able to access the meals another user adds. Can someone clarify this for me?

This is how I am reading and writing data right now.

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseDatabase
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var mealNameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var mealIngredientsField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var mealCountField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var mealPlanScrollView: UIScrollView!
    
    private let database = Database.database().reference()
    
    var meals: [String] = []
    var mealIngredients: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        database.child("meals").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
            snapshot in
            guard snapshot.value is [String] else {
                return
            }
            
            self.meals = snapshot.value as! [String]
        })
        
        database.child("mealIngredients").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
            snapshot in
            guard snapshot.value is [String] else {
                return
            }
            
            self.mealIngredients = snapshot.value as! [String]
        })
    }

    @IBAction func addMeal(_ sender: Any) {
        print("added")
        if let mealName = mealNameField.text, let mealIngredients = mealIngredientsField.text {
            if mealName != "" && mealIngredients != "" {
                meals.append(mealName)
                self.mealIngredients.append(mealIngredients)
                mealNameField.text = ""
                mealIngredientsField.text = ""
                
                database.child("meals").setValue(meals)
                database.child("mealIngredients").setValue(self.mealIngredients)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The way that you have it structured right now, it looks like there is just one table/document for all the users. You could structure in various different ways to make sure that there is a table for each user. No, each user does not get their own entire "database"

Comment: How can I structure it so that there is a table for each user?

Comment: You have a table for meals. Instead, make one for users. Store the meals as a child further down.